# Views counter doesn't increment in database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to add a view counter to my posts using F expressions and show the number of views for each post on django admin. But unfortunately, that doesn't work properly. I would be glad if anyone tells me what's wrong in my code.

**views.py:**

```
class Details(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['essential_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(essential=True).order_by('-created_on')
        return context
    def postviewcount(request, slug):
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        post.views = F('views') + 1
        post.save()
    template_name = 'post-detail.html'
```

**models.py:**

```
    STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'image/', blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    essential = models.BooleanField('Essential News', default = False)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Why do you expect `postviewcount` to be "triggered"?`

Comment: try post.refresh_from_db() if as @WillemVanOnsem said postviewcount is being triggered somehow

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm sorry I'm new to Django. You're right. How a function like that, inside a class, can be triggered?